# All convolution powers exist in $\ell^2$. Does the convolution theorem still hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What I have here is a sequence $c\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z^2)$ for which each convolution power $c*\ldots*c$ exists and is contained in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z^2)$, too. It is clear from $c\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z^2)$ that $c^{[2]} = c*c$ is contained in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z^2)$, but I actually know that $c^{[2]}\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z^2)$. Same for $c^{[3]} = (c*c)*c$ and so on...

Clearly the class of these sequences $c$ contains $\ell^1(\mathbb Z^2)$. But is it larger? In addition, I know that there exists some $n$ such that $c^{[n]}$ is a basis vector $e_m$.

What I would like to have is that $\widehat{c^{[n]}} = \hat c^n$ (convolution theorem), where $\hat d$ is the DTFT of $d\in\ell^2(\mathbb Z^2)$, i.e.,
$$
\hat d(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^2}d_ke^{-2\pi i\langle k,x\rangle},
$$
and that $\hat c$ is continuous (which both would be true if $c\in\ell^1(\mathbb Z^2)$).

Any idea anyone?

Comment: You want $c_k = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2i \pi k x}dx$ where $\displaystyle f \in  \bigcap_{p < \infty} L^p([0,1])$. But it is different to $L^\infty([0,1])$ because $\displaystyle \log x  \in  \bigcap_{p < \infty} L^p([0,1])$

Comment: You can try norms like $\displaystyle\|f\| =\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p!}\|f\|_{L^p([0,1])}$ but I think $\displaystyle f \in  \bigcap_{p < \infty} L^p([0,1])$ is still larger than the Banach space defined by $\|.\|$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just found out that I actually have $\hat c\in L^\infty([0,1]^2)$ because $|\hat c|=1$ almost everywhere. But does that imply that the convolution theorem holds here?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If $f^n \in L^2([0,1])$ and $c_k = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2i \pi k x}dx$  then $(\underbrace{c \ast \ldots \ast c}_n)_k = \int_0^1 f(x)^n e^{-2i \pi k x}dx$. So you want $f^n \in L^2([0,1])$ for every $n$ which is the same as $f \in L^p([0,1])$ for every $p$, but **it is different** to $f \in L^\infty([0,1])$